# Verify rdiff backup integrity

Tags: backup, data-integrity, rdiff-backup

I am using rdiff for my differential backup. Recently an issue happened where all versions of my backup failed to patch correctly and rdiff returning an error 106 which after investigation is a code for a corrupt delta.

Now I am pretty sure that the issue might be the result of a corrupt signature file since all deltas failed to patch correctly.

So my question is how do I verify if the signature file is corrupt or not or in other words how do I verify backups done using rdiff?

Comment: To find this, probably create a checksum(MD5) for those signature files that are successfully written. We can find the corrupted sig files by comparing the checksum of old to the new ones.

Comment: 'comparing the checksum of old to the new ones' I only generate a signature the first time? There aren't old and new signatures

Comment: It's not my cup of tea, but I guess it helps to edit the question to add the `rdiff` commands (or maybe `rdiff-backup`?) you're running, and the important parts of the output they're giving you? And also the important parts of `--debug`, `--version` and `--statistics`?

Comment: I don't know for sure if it's compatible, but maybe [Octodiff](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Octodiff/blob/master/README.md) can help, with: `octodiff explain-delta your-delta-file`, to see if it can read it?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the --verify option to try and run a verify on your backup and see what rdiff states?  Also looking at others output of --verify it appears that rdiff uses SHA1 and not MD5 signatures as the verification mechanism.  I also was reading that apparently if you have files with multiple hard links to them that on restore rdiff may not put them exactly back as they were.  There is someone who apparently came up with a patch but dunno if it has been blessed, included, or even widely available.

I was reading this thread after doing some searching on rdiff:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/rdiff-backup-users/2009-11/msg00054.html

you can use links on page to move back and forward to see the entire thread as it goes, but that page gave me most of my hints for what I have typed here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, the 'verify' action compares the backup repository to the stored hashes, and should report if those are mismatched.  not sure what to do about corrupted data/hashes though -- best thing would be to back up again from a clean source; if the backup is trashed and the data source is also gone, I guess you needed redundant backups :-(